# Segue and navigation controller interaction

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a segue set up from a main view controller to a detail view controller, but when it shows, the navigation bar remains the same as the source view - a "close" button and the main title. I'm expecting to see a "Back" button and the title for the detail screen I'm opening (I set the title in `prepareForSegue`). Xcode's editor shows a back button there, which is apparently triggered by connecting the segue.

More detail on the setup:

- The main screen is a navigation controller with a tab controller inside. The two tabs display different data but use the same table view controller class.
- Each tab contains a navigation controller with a table view controller.
- Each table view controller has a Show segue to the detail view controller.
- When a particular table item is tapped, the table view controller calls `performSegue(withIdentifier:,sender:)`
- The table view controller has `prepareForSegue` to pass data to the detail controller, and that much is working fine: the data shows up in the detail table.

[image]

The `prepareForSeque` code:

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
  switch segue.identifier {
    case SegueID.stringList:
      guard let listController = segue.destination as? StringListViewController,
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow,
            let stringListField = model.sections[indexPath.section].fields[indexPath.row/2]
                as? ListField<String>
      else { break }

      listController.strings = stringListField.values
      listController.navigationItem.title = stringListField.name
    default:
      break
  }
}
```

Curiously, Xcode does not show a Navigation Item for the detail view. I tried changing its Presentation from Full Screen to Current Context, but that made no noticeable difference.

How do I get this detail view to display its own navigation item and show a Back button?

Comment: A screenshot of your setup might help assert the problem. Also, are you using the `Show` or `Show Detail` kind on the segue in your storyboard?

Comment: It's the Show segue kind.

Comment: I just read your description, is the main screen a a navigation controller with a tabBar controller inside, and then each tab has it's own navigation controller (3 navController total)? Or is it a tabBarController with each tab having it's own navigationController (2 navControllers total)?

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: why do you have a navigationController as the entrance screen? What purpose does it serve? Maybe get rid of it and make the tabBar the main entrance

Comment: This isn't the main app screen; it shows when you open a project, so I need the navigation bar to show the title and close button.

Comment: @Uncommon What Lance Samaria said is right. Get rid of the main navigation controller and just have the tab bar controller as your root. That should fix your problem. But if you want to have it the way you set it up, then instead of having the show segue, push the detail view controller on top of the main navigation controller like so: `[self.tabBarController.navigationController pushViewController:myDetailViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: I don't understand how this isn't the main screen when the arrow is pointing to navigationController before the tabBar. You should try deleting it then moving the arrow to the tabBarController just to see what happens. You can always use the back button to go back and it will reappear. I don't know your entire set up but looking at this it's not correct to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screen shot it seems that the issue might be you have the tabBarController inside a navigationController.

You should use the TabBarController as the root view controller (arrow should point to it) and it shouldn't be embedded inside the stack of a navigation controller specifically it shouldn't be a navigationController's rootVC.

Read here [Apple -NavigationController rootViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621858-init)

> rootViewController The view controller that resides at the bottom of
>   the navigation stack. This object cannot be an instance of the
>   UITabBarController class.

Your below comments said that you rearranged everything by setting the tabBarVC as root to the application (arrow pointing to it) but it still didn't work. It's hard to identify the issue.

You should use print statements to find out which nav controller is doing the pushing, it might help you arrow down the problem.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // is this the very navController that has the tabBar as root or is this the one of the other ones?
    print("viewDidLoad: \(navigationController?.viewControllers.description as Any)") // this should print everything currently on the stack
}
```

Comment: No, that didn't help. I'm also already trying to set a `rightBarButtonItem` there.

Comment: No, I'm already trying to set that as well. It looks like this view controller's `navigationItem` just isn't getting used.

Comment: That's a strange problem, when you go to the debugger, using breakpoints, is the data getting transferred to the next vc?

Comment: You mean in `prepareForSegue`? Yes, the detail view controller is showing its content properly.

Comment: So the data is successfully  getting transferred in prepareToSeque, the detailVc is successfully getting pushed on, but its showing the incorrect navigation title and no back button?

Comment: Yes, the navigation bar doesn't change at all as the detail view animates onto the screen.

Comment: Its an odd problem. You should take a screenshot of your storyboard setup then show what's inside your tableView delegate methods and what's inside the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear of your detailVC. You can also try the code I posted inside viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear to see what happens. Very strange issue. I bet it's something small you overlooked, happens all the time.

Comment: @Uncommon Yeah, a screenshot would definitely help. You could blur out all the sensitive information in the screenshot

Comment: Did you get any results? I think I know what the problem is and it leads back to having the tabBar inside a nav as it's root. If your going to keep it that way add what's inside your prepareForSegue and I think I have a fix for you.

Comment: I added the code snippet. Removing the navigation controller did not help.

Comment: let me know if that works. If it doesn't I'll delete the extra code. I think the problem still has something to do with that initial vc that has the tab as root. You should put print statements inside the view viewDidLoad of all the vcs your using to see what nav is in control and the order of everything that is on the stack

Comment: Aha! Your question of which navigation controller is doing the pushing led me to the solution. The problem was that each tab item had its own navigation controller, and they were pushing the detail screen. Since they were nested, they didn't affect the navigation item being displayed. Sorry about all the back and forth. I tried to pare it down to the essential info, but it turns out I left out too much. I'll accept your answer since it put me on the right path.

Comment: Cool man, glad I can help! Yeah one thing I notice is the more info you give out the easier it is to dissect. Good luck coding!